# log4net: Specifying different layouts for different kinds of messages in the same RollingFileAppender

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

Apparently [two RollingFileAppenders cannot write to the same file](http://marc.info/?l=log4net-dev&m=116222149622609) (or has it changed since?).

So how can I write info messages with one layout and exceptions with another layout, both to the same rolling tile? Is it possible to specify two different layouts in the same appender, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really an issue of the (File)Appender, but much more so of the LockingModel behind it.

As "Random" has said, you might use the MinimalLock, note however, that it has two main disadvantages:

- Rather bad performance compared to ExclusiveLock, because the file lock is acquired/released for every message that is written.
- It just prevents two processes from writing concurrently. It may still happen that more than one process attempts to write to a single file. In this case only one will actually be granted, all others get errors and their messages are lost (also see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-164?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin)).

To circumvent this, you can write your own [LockingModel](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.LockingModelBase.html) which internally uses a Mutex. This is (a) faster then MinimalLock's filelocking and (b) still allows all processes to eventually write their message (even thouhg, as intendend of course, mutally exclusive). I have an implementation that I unfortunately cannot share, because it is from a customer's project. But it shouldn't be too hard to come up with an implementation (their might be one on the web, but I cannot find it just yet).

**Edit**: There is an implementation in this [mailing list thread](http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=120115526928894). Personally, I have not used it, so I cannot tell if it works, but it looks OK.

**Update**: Just happen to notice the "different layouts" part of the orginal question. I guess it is not possible to have a single appender using two different layouts. You could have two appenders which are equally configured, except for the layouts. Then have them write to the same file using a custom lockingModel or MinimalLock - YMMV. However, I really wouldn't do that. Having two layouts (formats!) in the same logfile makes parsing or log analysis unnecessary hard. Why not have two files in the first place then?

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. What puzzles me is this: Do I have to duplicate all the parameters of the appender, such as `rollingStyle` and `maximumFileSize`? It sounds really stupid to write them twice, because a file cannot have a maximum size of 100KB and 200KB at the same time. And what will happen if in the future someone tries to change one of the parameters without knowing that they are duplicated between the two appenders? Is this issue solvable?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: I guess if you have two (differently configured) appenders writing to the same file then whatever appender triggers a roll first, does it by its configuration. If A1 with 100KB seldom writes it will never see the 100KB limit happen, whereas A2 with 200KB may. If A1 writes often, effectively files will roll ever 100KB, because A2 will never see the 200KB limit. We have put the log4net configuration in a seperate file which is shared between components to make sure they use the same settings (more here http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: Ups, just saw the "different layouts" parts. I guess if you *really* want to do that you have to duplicate your appender configuration (including rollingStyle/maximumFileSize), since the layout is an embedded part of it - or you configure your appenders programmatically using the log4net API.

Comment: That's strange... Writing to the same file with two different layouts seems to me like a very reasonable scenario, and I'm surprised nobody thought of that... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding following element into FileAppender/RollingFileAppender elements of
each XML config file:

```
<param name="LockingModel" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

I'm using this to log from many log4net powered executables to a single file.